# Mapping an element to a list of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The Prelude function `map` in Haskell applies a function to a list of inputs:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

If we would like to apply an element to a list of functions, we could do this with recursion:

```
functionMap :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
functionMap element functions = case functions of
  []   -> []
  x:xs -> x element : functionMap element xs
```

How could we simplify the above recursion with higher order functions, such as `foldl`, `foldr` or `map`, if it is possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `map` over the `functions` and apply each to `element`:

```hs
functionMap :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
functionMap element functions = map (\f -> f element) functions
```

This can be shortened using the `$` operator to:

```hs
functionMap :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
functionMap element functions = map ($ element) functions
```

or just:

```hs
functionMap :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
functionMap element = map ($ element)
```

(also: `functionMap = map . flip id`)